# Using IF THEN and GOTO in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Following is a storedprocedure in which iam passing DriverID=0 and DrivarCode =DD1 and DriverName =Ram.
While executing control is going to fails.Control is coming to
  IF ((@DriverName!=NULL) and ((@DriverCode!=NULL)),After that going to fails. DriverName and DriverCode contains values.But still going to fails .What may be the reason for this

```
Create Procedure InsertUpdateM
(
    @DriverID int,
    @DriverCode varchar(50),
    @DriverName varchar(50),
    @Msg varchar(50) output
)

AS
BEGIN
IF @DriverID=0
    BEGIN
        SELECT DriverName,DriverCode FROM DriverM WHERE DriverName=@DriverName and DriverCode=@DriverCode
        IF(@@RowCount>0) GOTO Fails
            IF ((@DriverName!=NULL) and ((@DriverCode!=NULL))
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO DriverM(DriverCode,DriverName) values(@DriverCode,@DriverName)
                END
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT DriverName,DriverCode FROM DriverM WHERE DriverName=@DriverName and DriverCode=@DriverCode
        IF(@@RowCount>0) GOTO Fails
            IF ((@DriverName!=NULL) and ((@DriverCode!=NULL)
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE DriverM SET DriverCode=@DriverCode,DriverName=@DriverName WHERE DriverID=@DriverID
                END
    END
END

Fails
    SET @Msg='Failed'
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not even sure how this code parses. You have "Fails" after the end of the stored procedure, and it doesn't end with a colon. You want something more like this:

```
ELSE
    BEGIN -- Begin 1
        SELECT DriverName,DriverCode FROM DriverM WHERE DriverName=@DriverName and DriverCode=@DriverCode
        IF(@@RowCount>0) GOTO Fails
            IF ((@DriverName!=NULL) and ((@DriverCode!=NULL)
                BEGIN -- Begin 2
                    UPDATE DriverM SET DriverCode=@DriverCode,DriverName=@DriverName WHERE DriverID=@DriverID
                END  -- End of 2
    END -- End of 1

GOTO Succeeds
Fails:
    SET @Msg='Failed'
Succeeds:
END -- End of SP
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to achieve it.

```
Driverid:
    IF EXISTS(your query to check)
    BEGIN
        GOTO Driverid
    END
```